# Auto Populate Class Field

Tags: workflow, netsuite, suitescript

Good day! Guys, I'm new in creating workflow either script in NetSuite. Here's want I want to have "Once class is set in SO, it should be not be editable all throughout the process" . Is there a way to have this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a workflow/script, on field change event, that checks if the value in class field is not null. If the condition satisfies, set display type as "Disabled" or "readonly"

Comment: Yes but I don't know how to start. Thats my problem.